# General solution of ODE $\sum^N_{n=0} x^{(n)} = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a (funny?) question: Is it possible to give and if so, what would be the general solution of the ODE
$\sum^N_{n=0} x^{(n)} = 0$
where $x$ is an unknown function of one variable?

Comment: As this is a  linear problem, you can transform this to a multidimensional first-order problem (write it as $ y' = A y$ for some matrix $A$) and then find $\exp(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

assume the general solution of homogenous O.E is
$$x(t)=Ce^{rt}$$
so the characteristics equation will become
$$r^N+r^{N-1}+r^{N-2}+.....+1=0$$
find the roots to find the general solution as follows
$$x(t)=C_1e^{r_1t}+C_2e^{r_2t}+.....$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes I accept with you

Comment: You can find the roots by noting that $1$ is never a root of this equation and that for $r \neq 1$, $$(r^N + r^{N-1}+ ... + 1) = 0 \Leftrightarrow (1-r)(r^N + r^{N-1}+ ... + 1) = 0 \Leftrightarrow (1-r^{N+1}) = 0 $$ and thus the solutions are given by the roots of unity of order $N+1$ excluding $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The roots of $1+z+\dots + z^{N}=0$ are of the form $z_k=e^{2\pi i k /(N+1)}=\cos \theta_k + i\sin\theta_k$, for $k=1,2,3,\dots N$ and $\theta_k=\frac{2\pi k}{N+1}$.

So the general solutions to your equation are of the form:

$$x(t)=\sum_{k=1}^N a_i e^{z_kt}$$

That's gonna be terrible, but $e^{z_kt}=e^{t\cos\theta_k}\cos(t\sin\theta_k) + ie^{t\cos\theta_k}\sin(t\sin\theta_k)$.

So a "real" valued basis for $x(t)$ are the functions:

$$e^{t\cos \theta_k}\cos(t\sin\theta_k)\\
e^{t\cos\theta_k}\sin(t\sin\theta_k)$$

For $1\leq k\leq \frac{N+1}{2}$.